# Is conditional probability axiomatic?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, math-history, axioms

Is the conditional probability $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B), P(B) \ne 0$ an axiom in the Kolmogorov scheme or is it derived from the other axioms?

Comment: I would say it is not an axiom, it is a definition.

Comment: @RobPratt, that essentially answers my question. Do you know if it was part of the 1993 Foundations?

Comment: I think your question was intended for @GEdgar.

Comment: Correct. Apologies.

Comment: Are you talking about the 1933 book "foundations of the theory of probability? Then yes, there is a chapter called "immediate corollaries of the axioms, conditional probability, Theorem of Bayes.".

The point really is that a conditional probability defined for $P(B)\neq 0$ again fulfills the axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfréd Rényi provided a foundation of Probability Theory in which conditional probabilities were taken as primitives and axioms given for those primitives.

Rényi has a book on the subject (Rényi, A. (1970).Foundations of Probability. Holden-Day) but I don't think it is easy to find. The paper
"Conditional probability in Renyi spaces" by Gunnar Taraldsen is available as a [PDF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11038), and provides a starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Roger Purves. Didn't exactly answer the question but the paper was interesting if a bit above my pay grade. (Knew a Dr. Doug Purves once!)

Answer (score 5):

To give a more comprehensive answer, as GEdgar commented above in the original Kolmogorov formulation conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(\bullet\,|\,\bullet)$ is not included as an axiom, but is defined as an extra structure (see his *Foundations of the Theory of Probability*, 2e, Chelsea Publishing Company, p.6).

However at the same time there is a competing axiomatization of probability that takes a conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(\bullet\,|\, \bullet)$ as the primitive notion in a way compatible with the definition you cited. As Roger Purves cited in his answer, Rényi's book *Foundations of Probability* is based on this axiomatization. See also his earlier paper "On a new axiomatic theory of probability". According to this paper there were many others before him that detected that the axioms for a probability theory ought to be in terms of conditional probability (including Kolmogorov himself).

There are two reasons Rényi gives for the need for this conditional probability axiomatization:

1. The mathematical reason is that Kolmogorov takes the measure of a subset to be at most one, however in applications one encounters subsets of infinite measure; what is at most one ought to be conditional probabilities (this is along the lines of probability being asymptotic frequency of occurence; think laws of large numbers/ ergodic theorems).
2. The philosophical reason is that all probability is conditional probability (I find this declaration very insightful personally; I believe this not being clear is one of the things that makes naive probability confusing).

---

For the sake of completeness, here is Rényi's axiomatization of probability theory, using a conditional probability as a primitive (I'm following the version in the aforementioned paper; in the book the formulation is slightly different):

A **conditional probability space** is a quadruple $(S,\mathcal{E},\mathcal{C},\mathbb{P})$, where

- $S$ is a set whose elements are called **elementary events**,
- $\mathcal{E}\leq \mathcal{P}(S)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $S$, whose elements are called **events**,
- $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{E}$ is a nonempty collection of events whose elements are called **conditions**,
- $\mathbb{P}(\bullet\,|\, \bullet): \mathcal{E}\times\mathcal{C}\to[0,\infty]$ is a function satisfying

1. $\forall C\in \mathcal{C}: \mathbb{P}(C\,|\, C)=1$,
2. $\forall C\in\mathcal{C}: \mathbb{P}(\bullet\,|\, C):\mathcal{E}\to[0,\infty]$ is a measure,
3. $\forall E_1,E_2\in\mathcal{E},\forall C\in\mathcal{C}: E_2\cap C\in\mathcal{C} \implies \mathbb{P}( E_1 \,|\, E_2\cap C )\, \mathbb{P}( E_2  \,|\, C ) = \mathbb{P}( E_1\cap E_2 \,|\, C )$.

Comment: @Uzman thank you. This is very helpful indeed. I especially appreciate description of a conditional probability space. It also helped to understand why a 'new' approach was deemed necessary.